# How to store a set of objects and compare their object

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have a method that intakes a player's name(String), score(int), and date(String). I need help implementing a data structure that can store and link the parameters, so that I can compare the scores for each player.

I've tried creating an array that stores the top 5 scores, but when I print the top 5 scores, I have no way of printing the scores with their perspective player name and date.

```
public void addEntry (String playerName, int playerScore,String gameDate)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < top5Scores.length; i++){
        {
            top5Scores[i] = playerScore;
        }
}
```

I need to be able to print the top 5 scores which includes the playerName, playerScore, and the date. Also, I should be able to remove or add players using other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want is a wrapper class that implements the `Comparable` Interface. Then you can use methods like `Collections.sort()` to sort a Collection of PlayerStats Objects.

```
public class PlayerStats implements Comparable<PlayerStats> {

    private String playerName;
    private int playerScore;
    private String gameDate;

    public PlayerStats(String playerName, int playerScore, String gameDate) {
        this.playerName = playerName;
        this.playerScore = playerScore;
        this.gameDate = gameDate;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(PlayerStats o) {
        return Integer.compare(this.playerScore, o.playerScore);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Player: " + playerName + " Score: " + playerScore + "Date: " + gameDate;
    }

    public String getPlayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }

    public int getPlayerScore() {
        return playerScore;
    }

    public String getGameDate() {
        return gameDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I invoke the compareTo method? When I run my code it is not sorting my array of objects. It outputs my array of objects in the order it was inputted.

Comment: I select your answer because you did guide me in the right direction. I constructed an ArrayList of objects to contain each player account. I then override the compareTo method as you did except in my case I had to swap the position of this and o references. I then added Collections.sort(arr); to invoke compareTo method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What is the type of the array top5Scores?

Right now, it looks like it is an integer array.

Perhaps an array/list of objects would be a step in the right direction, i.e.

```
public class GameScore{
  int score,
  String playerName
  Date gameDate
  ...
}
```

Comment: I would make the date either a `String` or `LocalDate`.

Comment: It would be an Object type since I will be collecting a set of string, int, and string types. However, how would I be able to compare the int aspect of the array/list of objects?

Comment: @CSrook I would do that by having your GameScore class implement Comparable, and write a compareTo() method that will allow you to sort your array/scores using built in Collections.sort() provided by java